# How to use same child Page for multiple main pages

Tags: jquery, html, css

```
- Have 5 pages
- Each page has a link for "Sign-in/Log-in" on the topbar
- Lets say user is on "HomePage" and he clicks "Log-in" button on the topbar
- I want "Homepage" to go in background (opacity=0.2) and put the "Log-in" pop-up in front (z-index: 100)
- Same behavior is expected for all 5 pages -
```

What I have done is something like:

```
-----------------Page 1----------
div.HomePage
  div.accountPage
-----------------Page 2----------
div.BrowsePage
  div.accountPage
-----------------Page 3----------

...
```

Then I set opaqueness and z-index properties using javascript at run-time. I am repeating the code of accountPage 5 times in HTML/jade for each main page and also javascript code does not look clean for this approach.

```
- What I want is to create a TOTALLY SEPARATE "accountPage",
- Display on it click of "Login" button.
- Find out which of the 5 main pages user was on **/* This I dont know how to do */**
- Set that main page to background with opacity = 0.2
- Popup the accountPage for Login in front.
- After Login or cancel, bring the main page (user was on), back to focus
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a perfect candidate for an iframe or ajax based modal popup. There are many available for jQuery... [colorbox](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox) happens to be my favorite at the moment.

Here's how it works with colorbox:

1. Initialize colorbox on the sign-in links by targeting them by CSS class.
2. Set colorbox to use 'iframe' which will load your sign-in page within the popup
3. You can pass the current page along in the query string to the modal popup if needed, then retrieve it and process it on the signin page. For example: `<a href="/Sign-in/Log-in?returnUrl=[INSERT CURRENT URL HERE]" class="modal">Sign-in</a>` (NOTE: this can be done programmatically with `window.location.href` so that you don't have to hard-code the current URL into each link).
4. You can adjust the 'opacity' of the underlying page using CSS. It's actually a 100% height/width div that sits over the top of the page, however, it creates the illusion that the page is being 'dimmed' or faded out.
5. Upon closing the popup, the original page will reappear into focus, however, you can also perform a callback function to refresh the page (since the user is now signed in).

Comment: Let me try this. Appreciate your fast response.